# Block handling in bittorent

Tags: python, c, bittorrent

For the work I am currently doing I need similar functionality as Bittorrent, only difference is I need to do some sort of extra analysis on every block received by client from peers. Though I am fairly new with Python, I found official Bittorrent client source code easy to understand (as compared to Transmission's C source code). But I can't seem to figure out the part in the source code where it deals/handles every block received.
It'd be great if anyone, who is acquainted with Bittorrent official client source code (or Transmission), can provide me some pointers for the same.

Comment: You better put the part of code that you don't understand in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For Transmission, try looking at `libtransmission/peer-mgr.c` for code specific to each type of message received from a particular peer. This file represents the peer manager and all communication with it.
It uses `libtransmission/peer-msgs.c` for handling the exact messages.

Answer (score 0):

See line 156 [here](http://bittorrent.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bittorrent/BitTorrent/BitTorrent/Connecter.py?view=markup).

This paragraph fulfils SOs absurd minimum answer length requirement.